# JMeter 3.2 Remove warning of "file already exists" when starting a test

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-3.2

There's was a regression in version JMeter 3.2,

I started to get a new warning when running in GUI mode,

For every file defined in listeners there's a popup alert warning of "file already exists"

How can I remove this warning?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You cannot remove this warning as of 3.2 version. It's not a regression , it is meant to avoid accidentally overwriting previous results.

Please raise an enhancement feature at :

- http://jmeter.apache.org/issues.html

EDIT:

You created:

- https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=61068

It was implemented and will be available for 3.3.

A new property **resultcollector.action_if_file_exists** was introduced:

> Used to control what happens when you start a test and 
>   have listeners that could overwrite existing result files

Possible values:

- ASK : Ask user (default value that opens popup)
- APPEND : Append results to existing file
- DELETE : Delete existing file and start a new file

Comment: submitted for bug 61068

Answer (score 8):

1 .- Go to the folder where .bat file that Starts Jmeter is located. (Commonly bin folder)

2 .- Find the file jmeter.properties and opened with a text editor.

3 .- Search the #resultcollector.action_if_file_exists property and uncomment it (removing the # at the beginning)

4.- As the documentarion says above this parameter (inside the same file), there are 3 posible values for this:

```
#ASK : Ask user
#APPEND : Append results to existing file
#DELETE : Delete existing file and start a new file
```

For example, I changed to overwrite the files everytime y run my tests would be:

```
resultcollector.action_if_file_exists=DELETE
```

5.- Save the file and reestar Jmetter

Good Luck!